# Issues with having a method start after user input from custom dialog

Tags: java, android

Here's my situation. In my program the user presses a button and a custom dialog box appears requesting input. Once the user finishes, I need that information to be reflected in the activity that was running beforehand, via TextViews and ImageViews. I have a method which does this, but the problem is that once the user hits the original button, the codes goes into the next method which reflects the changes. I'm looking for a way to have the program wait until the dialog box finishes before proceeding to the next method which would update the information. What would be the best way to go about this? Any and all help is appreciated.

I've tried to update my code with the advice of using DialogFragments, but now I'm getting an error stating that there's a type mismatch can't convert BetType to DialogFragment. I have a class called BetType that extends DialogFragment. I'm following examples that' I see online and they're structured the same way. I'm at a stand still once again.

```
   private void selectBets() {
     if (betType != 1) {
       DialogFragment dialog = BetType(); //My error is here now
       dialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "bettype_Dialog");
     }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably be using a [DialogInterface.OnClickListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/DialogInterface.OnClickListener.html) to listen for the clicking of your dialog's OK button (or some equivalent button). The listener can call `displayBets()`. See [this page](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html) for several examples of how this type of listener can be used.

Comment: Question: My custom dialog is its own class with a custom xml. Can it call displayBets() since it's in a different class, cybersam?

Comment: Just because a dialog may have its own XML layout, it does not mean that it has its own class. See <http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#CustomLayout> for an example of how to use your own custom dialog layout. displayBets() and onCreateDialog() can be in the same Fragment. (But, even if they *were* in different classes, one should still be able to import and use the other.)

Comment: Hey @Cybersam, I just updated my code to reflect the changes we talked about before. For some reason, my code don't seem to recognize BetType as a dialogFragment. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Just wanted to share that I finally figured it out. Had a hard time with the imports and Fragment Manager, but I finally got it. Thanks for the assist

Answer (score 0):

Build a listener interface in the dialog.
Have your calling frag or activity implement it.

```
private OnFinishListener mOnFinishListener;

// Container Fragment must implement this interface
public interface OnFinishListener
{
    public void OnFinish();
}

public void onAttachFragment(Fragment fragment)
{
    try
    {
        mOnFinishListener = (OnFinishListener) fragment;

    } catch (ClassCastException e)
    {
        throw new ClassCastException(fragment.toString() + " must implement OnFinishListener");
    }
}

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    Log.i(TAG, "onCreateDialog");
    onAttachFragment(getParentFragment());
    ...
}
```

Then put this wherever you want to let the calling activity or fragment know.

```
if (mOnFinishListener != null)
    mOnFinishListener.OnFinish();
```

And your activity or fragment needs to implement it and call displayBets();

```
@Override
public void OnFinish() 
{   
    displayBets();
}
```

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#PassingEvents

Comment: Thanks uDevel. I'm going to try to implement your suggestion and i'll tell you how it works out.